# How to group by less columns than selected

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I'm facing a problem here (using SQL Server 2005).

My `SELECT` query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
a.str_column1, b.str_column2, c.date_column3, c.guid_column4
FROM table
....
joining the other tables here to get my columns
....
GROUP BY 
    a.str_column1, b.str_column2, c.date_column3, c.guid_column4
```

This will give something like this

```
a.str_column1    b.str_column2    c.date_column3    c.guid_column4
------------------------------------------------------------------
a1               b1                15/07/2013       someID    
a2               b2                05/06/2012       someID
a1               b1                07/08/2013       someID
....
```

Now I want so that it's grouped by `a.str_column1` and `b.str_column2`, only getting the most recent one (`order by c.dat_column3`)

```
a.str_column1    b.str_column2    c.date_column3    c.guid_column4
------------------------------------------------------------------
a1               b1                07/08/2013       someID
a2               b2                05/06/2012       someID
```

Any idea how I can accomplish this with SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), and may be able to eliminate the `GROUP BY` entirely:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
  SELECT 
  a.str_column1, b.str_column2, c.date_column3, c.guid_column4,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.str_column1, b.str_column2
                     ORDER BY c.date_column3 DESC) as rn
  FROM table
  ....
  joining the other tables here to get my columns
  ....
  --No longer needed GROUP BY a.str_column1, b.str_column2, c.date_column3, c.guid_column4
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

In order to be able to query on the result of the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, you have to place your existing query (with the new column in the `SELECT` list) into a subquery (as above) or a Common Table Expression.

Comment: I like this answer. I never had to use `OVER`/`PARTITION BY`, is there a site you can recommend reading into or would you just go for the MSDN description?

Comment: @seph - the MSDN page is all I'd usually link people to.

Answer (score 1):

You sholud use `max` function for `date_column3` column and remove the column from group by clause as below

```
SELECT 
a.str_column1, b.str_column2, max(c.date_column3) as column3, c.guid_column4
FROM table
....
joining the other tables here to get my columns
....
GROUP BY a.str_column1, b.str_column2,c.guid_column4
```

Comment: Though not clear from the sample data, I believe `guid_column4`will not be constant per `str_column1, str_column2`. I believe the intention is to get the latest `guid_column4` and the corresponding date