# Sort result when using ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is a follow-up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097341/how-to-group-by-less-columns-than-selected/18097418) question I asked yesterday.
I did not know if I should expand my original question, I decided to start a new one (bear with me...)

My `SELECT` is like this at the moment:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        a.guid_column1, b.guidID_column1, c.date_column1, d.guid_column1
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.guid_column1, b.guid_column1 ORDER BY c.date_column1 DESC) as rn 
    ...
    -- JOINS AND WHERE STUFF HERE
    ....
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

I get the (expected) result like this:

```
a.guid_column1   b.guid_column1    c.date_column1    d.guid_column1
-------------------------------------------------------------------
a1               b1                07/08/2013       someUniqueID
a2               b2                05/06/2012       someUniqueID
```

The tricky part is that I would like to sort that result by a `dateadd`, something like this `ORDER BY dateadd(month, a.float_column, c.date_column1) asc`
`a.float_column` is of course not always the same (and is in fact entered by the user later on).

Is there a way to accomplish this in SQL (I'm using SQL Server 2005)

Comment: Can you clarify "a.float_column is of course not always the same (and is in fact entered by the user later on)." a bit please?

Comment: Sure! It's a field on my form which is filled in by the user and is usually a number between 1 to 12.

Comment: Is the a.float_column always entered when running the query?

Comment: The query will be executed on an other form, so no.

Comment: so users enter the columns and how do you pass it to SQL Server? as comma delimited string?

Comment: I think i caused some misunderstanding here. I just wanted to point out that the months being add on to my original date (`c.date_column1`) are  not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below query will calculate the new date in the SELECT-CLAUSE.

If `a.float_column` is `NULL` nothing will be added to the original date.

```
SELECT dateadd(month, ISNULL(t.float_column,0), t.date_column1) as newDate
    , *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        a.guid_column1, b.guidID_column1, c.date_column1, d.guid_column1, a.float_column
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.guid_column1, b.guid_column1 ORDER BY c.date_column1 DESC) as rn 
    ...
    -- JOINS AND WHERE STUFF HERE
    ....
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1

ORDER BY newDate ASC
```

Comment: Usually ORDER BY 1 should be avoided (in case fields are added or the field order is changed).

Comment: Should I do this with an alias then for a calculated column?

Comment: I _don't_ think this will work, since both `a.float_column` and `c.date_column1` are being joined inside the subquery?

Comment: The `a` and `c` tables are not available at the point where you are using them. They are only available in the inner query.

Comment: Thank you Gabe, I changed the origin to 't'

Comment: @Hazaart, either by alias or by using the full function in the ORDER BY clause

Comment: actually your don't even need this column in your select, you could just write `order by dateadd(month, ISNULL(t.float_column,0), t.date_column1) asc`

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just add column into your subquery?

```
select *
from
(
    select
        a.guid_column1, b.guidID_column1, c.date_column1, d.guid_column1,
        dateadd(month, a.float_column, c.date_column1) as sort_order,
        row_number() over (partition by a.guid_column1, b.guid_column1 order by c.date_column1 desc) as rn 
    --
    -- JOINS AND WHERE STUFF HERE
    --
) t
where t.rn = 1
order by t.sort_order asc
```